# Any way to quickly access food in BOTW?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I find it really slow to have to go through several steps to just replenish my health, I would like some kind of quick access bar/shortcut that points to my food items, it would make the fights much more dynamic.

Do anyone know if there is such a thing? I couldn't find it if there is.

Comment: Great point.  I need food "on the fly" *way* more often than I need a shield, which is accessible from the direction buttons, like melee weapons are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sadly there is no such option.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, there's no way to do that, but it does pause the encounter so it shouldn't *really* be that big of a deal.

Comment: Sorry but that's a really bad justification. Not being able to quickly heal makes some battles extremely clunky.

Comment: It's not a justification so much as an observation for why it shouldn't affect someone in this way. Given the intentionality of the game design involved in BotW, I have to believe that this is by design. The physical buttons on the switch are very low and the trigger mechanisms are very fast. If you're sorting your items you should be able to navigate to what you want quickly within an hour or two of starting to play and grok the game. It's probably designed that way so that lower experienced players aren't so overwhelmed.

Comment: It is a QoL problem, and getting used to something slow and cumbersome doesn't mean it's OK, it means you got used to it. What I think is that they ran out of quick bar options and couldn't find a good alternative to access it quickly, so they left that out.  If I can navigate quickly or not it doesn't mean anything, I still have to navigate and it stops the flow of battle. Healing through shortcuts is a standard since forever, I understand in this case "food" is different from each other, but then give me a quick bar at least to not need to go to the main inventory.